# C++: Force lamba instances to have unique static variables

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

I would like to create a function that generates lambdas, where each of the lambdas has its own static variable. However, counter to what I thought would happen, the static variable seems to be shared between instances. For instance,

```
#include <iostream>

auto make_lambda(){
    return [](){
        static auto count = 0;
        return count++;
    };
}

int main() {
    auto a = make_lambda();
    auto b = make_lambda();
    std::cout << &a << ", " << a() << std::endl;
    std::cout << &b << ", " << b() << std::endl;
}
```

returns

```
0x7ffc229178df, 0
0x7ffc229178de, 1
```

So `a` and `b` seem to be unique instances, but are sharing that static count. I thought that I would see, and indeed want to see, something like

```
0x7ffc229178df, 0
0x7ffc229178de, 0
```

[live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oolptRy0DQZuWr4C)

What is the simplest way to make sure that the lambdas each have their own static variable?

Comment: If I may interject, why a static? If you copy `a` you expect the copy to see the same count? Do you intend to copy `a` at all?

Comment: Yes. That is precisely the behavior I seek

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ditch the static variable and use an extended lambda capture:

```
#include <iostream>

auto make_lambda(){
    return [count = 0]() mutable {
        return count++;
    };
}
```

If you want different lambda instances to share state with their respective copies but not between them, you can use a `std::shared_ptr` instead:

```
auto make_lambda(){
    return [count = std::make_shared<int>(0)]() mutable {
        return (*count)++;
    };
}
```

Comment: @StoryTeller weird feature, but here you go.

Comment: For our testing framework, it is very convenient to have some functionality that mimics Python generators. This will do the trick nicely.

Comment: @Quentin - Agree it's a requirement I can't divine the purpose off, but if that's what the OP wants :)

Answer (score 6):

You can leverage the fact that instantiated functions, and the templated entities they enclose, have their own copies of static variables defined in the function. Turning `make_lambda` into a template...

```
template<int>
static auto make_lambda(){
    return [](){
        static auto count = 0;
        return count++;
    };
}
```

... will generate a new static variable for each new template argument, unique to the TU (on account of the function template itself being `static`):

```
auto a = make_lambda<0>();
auto b = make_lambda<1>();
std::cout << &a << ", " << a() << std::endl;
std::cout << &b << ", " << b() << std::endl;
```

Which is not quite the syntax you wanted, but gets the job done. If you don't mind involving the preprocessor and potentially compiler extensions, you can get the simple function call syntax with a helper macro.

```
#define make_lambda() make_lambda<__COUNTER__>()
```

where `__COUNTER__` is a GCC extension that expands to a new number every time expansion is required in any single TU.

Comment: And then you have a *very* magical bug on your hands that corrupts data only when two calls line up perfectly across translation units ;) -- Edit: woops, that's `__COUNTER__`, not `__LINE__` a bit less magical but still quite problematic.

Comment: I mean that two different TUs will generate calls to `make_lambda<0>`, get instances of the same lambda type, and thus will share the static variable :)

Comment: @Quentin - I never encountered a problem with `__COUNTER__`. Though in the interest of full disclosure, I never actually used it for something like this. Compile time hashing of `__COUNTER__ + __LINE__ + __FILE__` would probably mitigate it further, but I think it might be going overboard with this...

Comment: Here's a [demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/t7FdYGA3HIlky6ob) -- note that the two seemingly independent calls in `main` produce `0` and `2`.

Comment: @Quentin - Or maybe... what if `make_lambda` was itself a `static` function template. Then everything will be unique to the TU. Edit, yeah, another static worked it out https://wandbox.org/permlink/lqUZFFa9s6zyCunp

Comment: Good call, that works. It's also the first time in my C++ life I've seen a use for a static function template... Fine, take my upvote :'

Comment: @Quentin - I swear C++ has a bunch of dusty tools that I think I'd never use, and then SO happens.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a variable by value to the lambda.
Moreover you have to make the lambda mutable so you'll be able to modify the value during execution. Normally labdas are like a const methods.

```
auto make_lambda(){
    int count = 0;
    return [count]() mutable {
        return count++;
    };
}
```